Collecting spatial data for highest accuracy possible
I am volunteering for a local project and collecting spatial data with a high accuracy GNSS unit. Since it is a large scale type project the site area is very small and I want to get the most accurate data I can. So my unit will be collecting the data in NAD 1983 (2011) and my RTK corrections will also be coming through using the same GCS.
Will my data be as accurate as can be if I am projecting the data to WGS 1984 web aux. sphere OR should I upload a new base map with the same GCS and state plan project to collect the data in. This is so a transformation is not introduced.
The way I understand it is.... As long as my data is being collected in the correct datum I am good when it comes to accuracy right? At the end of the day I just don't want my point data to have a great deal of accuracy errors in terms of distance from each other.
For clarity, I am collecting into ArcGIS Field Maps which requires a Location Profile in order for a transformation to take place between the GPS unit and the maps coordinate system you are collecting into. The things is, I do not want to transform anything if I do not have too.

Do you have a base station  and/or Rover ?  "The accuracy of RTK networks is relative to the base station's accuracy. If a DIY base is poorly surveyed or moved, it can invalidate all previous mapping," https://pointonenav.com/news/is-build-your-own-rtk-really-worth-it/ can be costly.

Yes I am using local base station only about 30 miles away
